# Failed to compile XML files with aapt2 - 'invalid file path'

Tags: android, xml, compilation

I read the documentation about the use of `aapt2` [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2).  In particular the `Compile` section.

I have a decompiled `AndroidManifest.xml` file (with `apktool`) from some application and now I want to re-compile it back.

When I am using `aapt2` to do it like that:

```
C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\26.0.2\aapt2.exe compile C:\tmp\AndroidManifest.xml -o c:\tmp\compiled_folder
```

It is failed with the error:

> error: invalid file path 'C:\tmp\AndroidManifest.xml'.

Why it writes me that the file is `invalid` ? it's a regular XMLfile.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use only files from the resource folder because it supports only resource files:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources

And `AndroidManifest.xml` is not consider as resource.